# Замена елемента строки в файле QFile

Tags: qt, строки, файлы, qt5, qstring

есть программа в Qt5 и есть файл, в файле записано примерно так:

> Иван Иванов +380000000000 5

Она записывает человека, а потом должна найти его по номеру телефона. Мне нужно взять 3 элемент (в данном случае это цифра 5), заменить его на другое значение. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Придется перезаписывать весь файл.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста примерный код для этого?